Multiply two different Dataframes - Python
I have two tables:
Table 1: (Sales)



Code
2025
2026
2027




123
20000
21000
22000


456
10000
12000
14000



Table 2: (Inflation)



Code
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028




123
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4


456
0.55
0.65
0.75
0.85
1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5



By using Python, I want to update Table (1) values by the inflation. for example for code "123" year "2025" which equal before inflation 20000. this value (20000) need to be updated by inflation rate located in table (2) which is equal 1.1 (the intersection of row 123 with column 2025 in table (2)). and the same for the other values.
The resulted table (1) should be:



Code
2025
2026
2027




123
22000
25200
28600


456
12000
15600
19600




Using a for loop as suggested by other answers would work, but you can also use the built-in pandas mul function like this:
import pandas as pd

# Create the two tables
sales_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2025: [20000, 10000],
    2026: [21000, 12000],
    2027: [22000, 14000]
})

inflation_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2020: [0.6, 0.55],
    2021: [0.7, 0.65],
    2022: [0.8, 0.75],
    2023: [0.9, 0.85],
    2024: [1, 1],
    2025: [1.1, 1.2],
    2026: [1.2, 1.3],
    2027: [1.3, 1.4],
    2028: [1.4, 1.5]
})

# Set the index of both DataFrames to 'Code'
sales_df = sales_df.set_index('Code')
inflation_df = inflation_df.set_index('Code')

# Select the relevant columns from the inflation_df
inflation_subset = inflation_df[sales_df.columns]

# Apply the inflation to the sales
updated_sales_df = sales_df[inflation_subset.columns].mul(inflation_subset, axis=0)

# Reset the index and update the column names
updated_sales_df = updated_sales_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Code'})

print(updated_sales_df)

Output:
   Code     2025     2026     2027
0   123  22000.0  25200.0  28600.0
1   456  12000.0  15600.0  19600.0


You can use df.columns and multiply it:
import pandas as pd


sales = {
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2025: [20000, 10000],
    2026: [21000, 12000],
    2027: [22000, 14000]
}


inflation = {
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2020: [0.6, 0.55],
    2021: [0.7, 0.65],
    2022: [0.8, 0.75],
    2023: [0.9, 0.85],
    2024: [1, 1],
    2025: [1.1, 1.2],
    2026: [1.2, 1.3],
    2027: [1.3, 1.4],
    2028: [1.4, 1.5]
}

dfs = pd.DataFrame(sales)
dfi = pd.DataFrame(inflation)


dfs.set_index('Code', inplace=True)
dfi.set_index('Code', inplace=True)

for year in dfs.columns:
    dfs[year] *= dfi[year]

dfs.reset_index(inplace=True)


print(dfs)


Prints
   Code     2025     2026     2027
0   123  22000.0  25200.0  28600.0
1   456  12000.0  15600.0  19600.0



You can use DataFrame.columns.intersection to quickly find the overlapping columns across multiple DataFrames. Then you can multiple those overlaps.
import pandas as pd

# Create the two tables
sales_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2025: [20000, 10000],
    2026: [21000, 12000],
    2027: [22000, 14000]
})

inflation_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': [123, 456],
    2020: [0.6, 0.55],
    2021: [0.7, 0.65],
    2022: [0.8, 0.75],
    2023: [0.9, 0.85],
    2024: [1, 1],
    2025: [1.1, 1.2],
    2026: [1.2, 1.3],
    2027: [1.3, 1.4],
    2028: [1.4, 1.5]
})

inflation_df = inflation_df.set_index('Code')
sales_df = sales_df.set_index('Code')

shared_cols = inflation_df.columns.intersection(sales_df.columns) # find overlapping/shared columns
sales_df[shared_cols] *= inflation_df[shared_cols]                # update columns in sales_df multiplied by inflation_df

print(sales_df)
#          2025     2026     2027
# Code
# 123   22000.0  25200.0  28600.0
# 456   12000.0  15600.0  19600.0

